# Running Webrick in Windows - Help getting started with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, webrick

I'm new to Ruby on Rails (and programming!) and am running through the guide here...

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

However I am stumped on step 4.1. Creating a webserver as Webrick does not seem to run at all. Here is the error message that I see...

> F:/Documents/Google Drive/Development/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4
>   .2.0/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:39:in `exec': No such file or directory - "F:
>   /Documents/Google Drive/Development/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe" (Errno::ENOENT)

The Ruby.exe does indeed exist in this location, all previous steps have been fine up until now. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is Ruby and Rails installed locally or is it in an external flash drive or cloud storage? You might need to reinstall everything into your C:\ drive to run a local server.

Also, did you copy the command from the guide verbatim? If you're running windows and using a cmd prompt, you don't need to include the "bin/" part of that command. Simply enter "rails server" or "rails s" for short to start the server.